# Как добавить простой текст в окне 'matplotlib' под Pie Chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, диаграммы, визуализация

[image: Как добавить текст отдельный от параметров бублика но что бы он отображался в окне matplotlib]

Как добавить простой текст в окне 'matplotlib'  под Pie Chart ?
нужна отдельная область для написания текста что бы не было связи с параметрами самого бублика.
Написать примечания или коментарий не более того.
Я находил решения вроде Title и SubTitle но оно все завязано на осях X, Y и это не дает мне опускать строку текста ниже как на картинке.
Спасибо тому кто поможет.

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    # Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
    labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
    sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
    explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')
    
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
            shadow=True, startangle=90)
    ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
    
    plt.show()
```

как я пробую: ax1.set_title("Matplotlib bakery: A donut")

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    # Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')
    
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
            shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
ax1.set_title("Matplotlib bakery: A donut")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Да вроде всё получается, если задать отрицательные координаты. Нужно только их подобрать:

```
ax1.text(-0.7,-1.5, 'Пай чарт', fontsize=32)
```

Хотя можно даже ещё проще, просто задать подпись `x`-координате и не нужно подбирать координаты, надпись сама отцентрируется:

```
ax1.set_xlabel('Пай чарт', fontsize=32)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если задать отрицательные координаты. Нужно только их подобрать.  Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @AlphaObelisk Я нашёл способ ещё проще, добавил код